# Generating DataFrame from Key Value Pairs

Tags: pandas

I have a list of dictionaries with key value pairs that I would like to create a DataFrame from and I thought that the `from_items()` method would be the simplest method to do so, but it appears that attribute does not exist. What could be wrong about my approach that is throwing the error and is there a better method to do this?

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'from_items'
```

Dictionary (`col_vals`):

```
{'id': 'people5',
   'title': 'Stakeholder',
   'text': '',
   'type': 'multiple-person',
   'value': None
},
{'id': 'people5',
   'title': 'Stakeholder',
   'text': 'Test',
   'type': 'multiple-person',
   'value': 'Michael'
}
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
col_vals = data['column_values']

for i in col_vals:
    print(i.items())
    df.from_items(i.items())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have:

```
ldicts = [{'id': 'people5',
   'title': 'Stakeholder',
   'text': '',
   'type': 'multiple-person',
   'value': None
},
{'id': 'people5',
   'title': 'Stakeholder',
   'text': 'Test',
   'type': 'multiple-person',
   'value': 'Michael'
}]
```

You can use the pd.DataFrame constructor like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ldicts)
df
```

Output:

```
        id        title  text             type    value
0  people5  Stakeholder        multiple-person     None
1  people5  Stakeholder  Test  multiple-person  Michael
```